# Parse routes in cakephp to load specific model (is it possible to use .htaccess for this?)

Tags: cakephp, model, routes, cakephp-1.3

First part of this question will look trivial, but the point is in second part.

So, let's say that I have next few links on my app:

```
http://myapp.com/cars-audi
http://myapp.com/cars-opel
http://myapp.com/cars-fiat
http://myapp.com/cars-vw
```

In these cases, model car is used. So, in this case, I want to escape using slash in URL.

Then I will have more pages, and URLs, where roads will be involved, like:

```
http://myapp.com/roads/germany
http://myapp.com/roads/austria
http://myapp.com/roads/hungary
http://myapp.com/roads/poland
```

So, if it starts with **cars-**, in that case model cars should be used, and if it starts with **roads/**, model roads will be in the game.

Is it possible to do with some regular expressions in routes.php, or is it better to load (use) one same model in both cases, and to work with them like that?

Also, is it possible to help  parsing URL using .htaccess file?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why different separators for cars and roads?

Comment: that's requested from seo personal

Comment: i never used routing for a case like that, but first of all you are not using models, you are using controllers and call their actions.
Models are used in the controller to get the data you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple case of routing a URL to a controller action, it doesn't involve models at all.

```
Router::connect('/:carlink',
                array('controller' => 'cars', 'action' => 'view'),
                array('carlink' => 'cars-\w+', 'pass' => array('carlink')));
```

This route says *any URL that matches `/:carlink` should be routed to the given controller and action*. In the last part you're clarifying what `:carlink` can be with the regular expression `cars-\w+` ("cars-" followed by any word). You also pass that value to your called action.

```
class CarsController extends AppController {
    public function view($car) {
        if (!preg_match('/cars-(\w+)/', $car, $matches)) {
            // action was accessed with invalid URL, bail out
            $this->cakeError('error404');
        }

        // use $matches[1], which will be 'audi', for example
        …
    }
}
```

Your road URLs would be routed to the RoadsController as usual like this:

```
Router::connect('/roads/*', array('controller' => 'roads', 'action' => 'view'));
```